# Flutter grid view scroll to bottom

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have one screen with `GridView`. When I move to this page I have `GridView` items count, and I want open this page and show `GridView` starting at the bottom. Now I do

```
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (_parameters.scrollToBottom && _controller.hasClients) {
        _controller.jumpTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
      }
    });
```

but I think this is not good way to do this. Can I do this by another way?

Comment: Would you mind to explain that why it is not a good solution, any bug or efficiency issue?

Comment: I think this solution not good solution, I want know best practice doing something like this

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of doing it. Please try this.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ScrollController gridScrollController = ScrollController();
  List<String> images = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614961234425-dedd96e5e699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    /*Or you can also use Timer*/
    // Timer(
    //   Duration(seconds: 1),
    //   () => gridScrollController
    //       .jumpTo(gridScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent),
    // );
    
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {

      gridScrollController
          .jumpTo(gridScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 12.0,
        ),
        child: Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            controller: gridScrollController,
            itemCount: images.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10.0),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Image.network(images[index]);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or you can also try this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (gridScrollController.hasClients) {
      setState(() {
        gridScrollController
            .jumpTo(gridScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
      });
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 12.0,
        ),
        child: Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            controller: gridScrollController,
            itemCount: images.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10.0),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Image.network(images[index]);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but I think this is bad solution, I want just open and see ``gridView`` bottom items. And I don't want render items in top of ``gridView``

Comment: It will not render bottom items instead it scrolls to bottom of the page

Comment: You can also try this, please refer above updated code `if (gridScrollController.hasClients) {
      setState(() {
        gridScrollController
            .jumpTo(gridScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
      });
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to reverse how `GridView` lays out its children starting from bottom to top. Luckily for us, `GridView` has a reverse property.

Here is an example on how you can use it:

```
GridView.count(
  reverse: true, // Set reverse to true
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: List.generate(100, (index) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'Item $index',
      ),
    );
  }),
);
```